# Lightning Component with Clickable Links

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura

I'm working on a contact related list lightning component and trying to make the contacts clickable so that the user can navigate to the contact record page if clicked. I am iterating through the contacts and "trying" to use an `<a href>` tag to navigate the user. Currently, I have

```
<aura:iteration items="{v.ListofContacts}" var="con">
     <td scope="row">
           <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!con.Name}" ><a href="/{con.Id}"> {!con.Name}<a/></div>
```

Comment: 2 questions, why are you not using lightning-web-components, and for aura, why aren't you using force:navigateToURL ?

Comment: What's the issue? You told us what you're doing, but what's happening when a user clicks on your hyperlink?